# What does the $ character mean in React Native?

Tags: react-native

With regard to props in React Native, what does the $ refer to?

e.g. 
backgroundImage: 'url(${contact.avatarURL})'

Comment: I now understand that the ${myVariable} is an innovation of JavaScript ES6 whereby you can display output from variables inline with text instead of using the + symbol to chain text and variables together.  For example, before you might code "I am " + age + "years old."  and now you can clean it up by coding, "I am ${six} years old."  Then, when applied in React Native it helps streamline syntax very effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called Template Literals (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

$ refers to the var/let/const that you want embed in a string.

example :

```
const location = "Bali";

console.log(`Hello, ${location}`); //Hello, Bali
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ES6 string interpolation/template literals with ` (backticks) and ${expr} (interpolated expression).

[Resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

Answer (score 0):

It's refers to Template Literals, you can read in official documentation **`ReactNative`** :  [Javascript Syntax Transformers](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.47/docs/javascript-environment.html#javascript-syntax-transformers).

Or

Learn documentation about **`ES6`** : [ES6 Feature](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/).